# How to convert a C# dictionary to a collection

Tags: c#, json

I have a C# dictionary list as follows:

```
"additionalDataList": [
                {
                    "key": "notes",
                    "value": "haasdas\n\ns"
                },
                {
                    "key": "twigTemplateId",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "AssignedUser",
                    "value": {
                        "Name": "To, To",
                        "Id": 108
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "assignedUserId",
                    "value": "114"
                }
            ],
```

But, I need to convert this like:

```
"additionalDataList": 
                    {
                     
                        "notes": "haasdas\n\ns"
                    },
                    {
                
                        "twigTemplateId": "2"
                    },
                    {
                       
                        "AssignedUser": {
                            "Name": "To, To",
                            "Id": 108
                        }
                    },
                    {
                       
                        "assignedUserId": "114"
                    }
```

How can I get the expected result? I tried to convert in List Object, but did not work.

**Update:**
Code that I have:

```
 public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> AdditionalDataList { get; set; }

        public string AdditionalData {
            get
            {
                return _additionalData;
            }
            set
            {   if (!(value is null))
                {
                    AdditionalDataList = ParseJson(value).ToList();
                }
                _additionalData = value;
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> ParseJson(string json)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (json is null)
            {
                return dict;
            }

            var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach (var property in obj)
            {
                var name = property.Key;
                var value = property.Value;

                if (value is JArray)
                {
                    dict.Add(name, value.ToArray());
                }
                else if (value is JValue)
                {
                    dict.Add(name, value.ToString());
                }
                else if (value is JObject)
                {
                    dict.Add(name, JObject.Parse(value.ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Invalid JSON token type.");
                }
            }

            return dict;
        }
```

I need to convert the following JSON String: (This is already in Additional Data)

```
{"notes":"haasdas\n\ns","twigTemplateId":2,"AssignedUser":{"Name":"To, To","Id":108},"assignedUserId":114}
```

Comment: First you need to deserialize your json to data. Second you need some projection on that data and last serialize it back to json. So what did you try already and where do you need our help **specifically**?

Comment: The usage of the term `collection` in the title is not correct.

Comment: Yes, may be you right. I did not know what I actually need for the expected result @WΩLLE-ˈvɔlə

Comment: The format of what you want is not legal JSON, as such you won't get any of the typical JSON (de)serialization libraries to produce it. You will have to either serialize to legal JSON and then edit it, or write the serializer yourself.

Comment: As @LasseV.Karlsen mentioned, that is not valid JSON so you won't find libraries to parse it or to serialize to such format, and will have to do both parts manually. Begs the question of why you want to generate such invalid json

Comment: What do you mean by legal JSON? I have JSON string in DB. I need to retrieve that and after that I need to convert that as JSON Object. That is only my purpose. If the dictionary is not the needed thing. I don't have  problem. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: {"notes":"haasdas\n\ns","twigTemplateId":2,"AssignedUser":{"Name":"To, To","Id":108},"assignedUserId":114} This is not a valid JSON string? @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: The second code block (which you say is what you want) is not valid JSON. The last code block is valid JSON. Can you [edit] your question and make it extremely clear what you want?

Comment: Change type of `AdditionalDataList` to `Dictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` for your property `AdditionalDataList`  does not represent your desired json. Common convention is to serialize `Dictionary` to JSON object with keys used as names (and not a collection of `KeyValuePair`, because as per [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-4) names should be unique):

```cs
public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalDataList { get; set; }
```